# Passing image data to Tensorflow lite (micro)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite, esp32

I've got a tensorflow model that's been built pretty much exactly following the tutorial at

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

I'm doing the normalisation outside of the model though so I've got

```py
normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)
normalized_train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
normalized_val_ds = val_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
```

```py
model = Sequential([
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
```

It all seems to work, passes the epochs with high validation accuracy etc

I'm then exporting to tensorflow lite via

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS]
```

Which I'm loading into an ESP32 & after a lot of trail and error it's running alright.
However I'm not getting predictions on the ESP32.

(where `framebuffer` is definitely an array of Red, Blue, Green bytes (0 - 255))

```cpp
float *runPrediction(uint8_t *framebuffer, size_t length)
{
  TfLiteStatus tflite_status;
  static float prediction[NUMBER_OF_OUTPUTS] = {0};

  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    model_input->data.f[i] = (1.0f / 255) * framebuffer[i];
  }

  tflite_status = interpreter->Invoke();

  // display model_output etc
}
```

**I'm trying to re-do the normalisation / conversion to floats before passing it in but I think I might be going wrong there?**

I'm not getting any error messages / crashes & the model is running, it's just that none of the outputted predictions go very far above 0.00.

I trained the model on jpegs originally, but at QQVGA resolution (160x120) the JPEG noise is bad so I've been augmenting the training data with raw .bmp images from the sensor in situ - but that hasn't really helped so hopefully it's something in code.

I'm sure the input framebuffer is an array of R, G, B bytes since I'm outputting a debug view using it where I'm converting it to RGB565.

I have seen prior models return values above 0.01 but I think that was just noise.

The input shape is said to be `[  1 120 160   3]` & `float32`, I'm guessing I need to match this somehow in the c++ code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the correct way to pass an image to Tensorflow lite on a microcontroller.

What I was doing wrong ways using the non-normalised data as the `representative_dataset` values, so the model was being quantised to expect floats of 0-255 even though it could only deal with 0-1.

Using the normalised data as the reference I've got the model returning sensible things now.